# Jsoup - The text within a tag itself XML

Tags: java, xml, jsoup

So i have XML page that i need to extract information from but the information needed is actually in the tag.

I can extract text between tags succesfully and extract everything including tags but i am unsure how to narrow down within a tag.

Example

```
<incident last-updated-dt="1401950400000" longitude="146.56256387822685" latitude="-38.39289894161029" resource-count="0" incident-no="58">
```

I want to be able to get the longitude and latitude which is within the incident tag.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can extract data:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse("<incident last-updated-dt='1401950400000' longitude='146.56256387822685' latitude='-38.39289894161029' resource-count='0' incident-no='58'>");
Element element = doc.select("incident").first();
String tagName = element.tagName();
System.out.println("Tag name : " + tagName);
for(Attribute attr : element.attributes())
{
    System.out.println(attr.getKey() + " : " + attr.getValue());
}
```

And results are:

```
Tag name : incident
last-updated-dt : 1401950400000
longitude : 146.56256387822685
latitude : -38.39289894161029
resource-count : 0
incident-no : 58
```